# Print result from 2 queries in different columns of one table

Tags: sql

I am trying to output result from 2 queries in one table but no luck. Tried with `UNION` and with this template

```
SELECT x.a, y.b FROM (SELECT * from a) as x, (SELECT * FROM b) as y
```

with no luck. My queries are:

```
Select
    Sum('.MAIN_DB_PREFIX.'facturedet.qty) As qty_sum,
    '.MAIN_DB_PREFIX.'user.firstname,
    '.MAIN_DB_PREFIX.'user.lastname,
    '.MAIN_DB_PREFIX.'user.rowid,
    '.MAIN_DB_PREFIX.'facture.datef,
    '.MAIN_DB_PREFIX.'user.rowid
From
    '.MAIN_DB_PREFIX.'facturedet 
Inner Join
    '.MAIN_DB_PREFIX.'facture On '.MAIN_DB_PREFIX.'facturedet.fk_facture = '.MAIN_DB_PREFIX.'facture.rowid Inner Join
    '.MAIN_DB_PREFIX.'societe_commerciaux On '.MAIN_DB_PREFIX.'societe_commerciaux.fk_soc = '.MAIN_DB_PREFIX.'facture.fk_soc Inner Join
    '.MAIN_DB_PREFIX.'user On '.MAIN_DB_PREFIX.'societe_commerciaux.fk_user = '.MAIN_DB_PREFIX.'user.rowid
Where
    ".MAIN_DB_PREFIX."facture.datef Between Date_Format(Now(), '%Y-%m-01') And CurDate()
GROUP BY
    '.MAIN_DB_PREFIX.'user.rowid
ORDER BY 
    qty_sum DESC
```

and

```
Select
    Sum('.MAIN_DB_PREFIX.'facture.total) As total_sum,
    '.MAIN_DB_PREFIX.'user.firstname,
    '.MAIN_DB_PREFIX.'user.lastname,
    '.MAIN_DB_PREFIX.'user.rowid,
    '.MAIN_DB_PREFIX.'facture.datef,
    '.MAIN_DB_PREFIX.'user.rowid
From
    '.MAIN_DB_PREFIX.'facture Inner Join
    '.MAIN_DB_PREFIX.'societe_commerciaux On '.MAIN_DB_PREFIX.'societe_commerciaux.fk_soc = '.MAIN_DB_PREFIX.'facture.fk_soc Inner Join
    '.MAIN_DB_PREFIX.'user On '.MAIN_DB_PREFIX.'societe_commerciaux.fk_user = '.MAIN_DB_PREFIX.'user.rowid
Where
    ".MAIN_DB_PREFIX."facture.datef Between Date_Format(Now(), '%Y-%m-01') And CurDate()
GROUP BY
    '.MAIN_DB_PREFIX.'user.rowid
ORDER BY
    total_sum DESC
```

With both `UNION` or combined query as mentioned above, I get blank result and no errors.

Also, I cannot wrap the select in brackets and use an alias like `(query) a UNION (query2) b` as this also brings blank output.

I can output first name + last name in column one of a table, sum_qty on second, some calculation is made based on the qty and it goes in the third column. In the fourth column, I need to output `total_sum`

Digged here like 20 threads and tried different solutions but no result.

Full code: https://pastebin.com/bie0LXH9

Comment: I'd suggest your first step is to change your "Inner Join"s to "Left Outer Join"s, and then see what results you get.  In reality, if the queries themselves are OK (and those do appear to be), and you can also see data if you query the individual tables, then the two things that are going to restrict what data appears in a larger query are a) JOINs (where the joined values don't exist between tables), or b) WHERE clauses.  We can't see your data, and we don't know what value the "CurDate()" function is returning.  Changing to Left Outer Joins might highlight join values that don't exist

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/NtDGJg4.png - this is the tables structure.

Comment: You should use full join for this two queries

Comment: What template do you mean? Like: ```Select ..... Union Select ....``` and change all 'inner joint' to 'Left Outer Join' or ...

Comment: @milenmk - the table structure itself is not particularly relevant in troubleshooting this issue (I've assumed the tables/columns in your query are valid).  What's important is the actual data records themselves, that are being used to compared against the JOIN predicates and the WHERE clause.  Hence the reason why I suggested temporarily changing to LEFT OUTER JOINs, which will mean that rows will be returned even if there are not valid relationships (for a particular row) between all of the tables.  You could also widen the date range of the WHERE clause to see if that's limiting the rows

Comment: Each query is working independantly> The problem, in fact, is that the first query is `$sql ... ` and the second is `$sql2`. And then, I need to use ONE `$resql = $db->query($sql) or die($db->error); while($row = $resql->fetch_assoc()` to output the result. Just tried `SELECT UNION SELECT` with `Inner Join` changed to `Left Outer Join` and the output is only from the second select. No brackets around SELECTs, and `GROUP BY` is at the end.

Comment: Full code here: https://pastebin.com/bie0LXH9

Comment: Oh, I see - I've misunderstood, sorry.  However, now that you've given that explanation, and shown the html output that you're attempting to generate, your approach of trying to combine those two separate queries with a UNION is not correct.  I'll post an answer that I think will get you what you're after

Comment: Actually, I was thinking this would be achieved using a Common Table Expression, but you haven't actually specified which RDBMS you are using.  Can you advise?  (Also, note which version of RDBMS, since CTEs may not be supported, depending on your version)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should achieve the desired result (ie. the resultset that you need to output your table) using the UNION that you were attempting (although a more efficient query could possibly be achieved using a Common Table Expression - which may or may not be available to you, depending on your RDBMS, and the version thereof).

```
SELECT
    firstname,
    lastname,
    rowid,
    SUM(IFNULL(qty_sum, 0)) AS qty_sum,
    SUM(IFNULL(total_sum, 0)) AS total_sum
FROM
(
Select
    Sum('.MAIN_DB_PREFIX.'facturedet.qty) As qty_sum,
    0 AS total_sum,
    '.MAIN_DB_PREFIX.'user.firstname,
    '.MAIN_DB_PREFIX.'user.lastname,
    '.MAIN_DB_PREFIX.'user.rowid
From
    '.MAIN_DB_PREFIX.'facturedet 
Inner Join
    '.MAIN_DB_PREFIX.'facture On '.MAIN_DB_PREFIX.'facturedet.fk_facture = '.MAIN_DB_PREFIX.'facture.rowid Inner Join
    '.MAIN_DB_PREFIX.'societe_commerciaux On '.MAIN_DB_PREFIX.'societe_commerciaux.fk_soc = '.MAIN_DB_PREFIX.'facture.fk_soc Inner Join
    '.MAIN_DB_PREFIX.'user On '.MAIN_DB_PREFIX.'societe_commerciaux.fk_user = '.MAIN_DB_PREFIX.'user.rowid
Where
    ".MAIN_DB_PREFIX."facture.datef Between Date_Format(Now(), '%Y-%m-01') And CurDate()
GROUP BY
    '.MAIN_DB_PREFIX.'user.rowid

UNION ALL

Select
    0 AS qty_sum,
    Sum('.MAIN_DB_PREFIX.'facture.total) As total_sum,
    '.MAIN_DB_PREFIX.'user.firstname,
    '.MAIN_DB_PREFIX.'user.lastname,
    '.MAIN_DB_PREFIX.'user.rowid
From
    '.MAIN_DB_PREFIX.'facture Inner Join
    '.MAIN_DB_PREFIX.'societe_commerciaux On '.MAIN_DB_PREFIX.'societe_commerciaux.fk_soc = '.MAIN_DB_PREFIX.'facture.fk_soc Inner Join
    '.MAIN_DB_PREFIX.'user On '.MAIN_DB_PREFIX.'societe_commerciaux.fk_user = '.MAIN_DB_PREFIX.'user.rowid
Where
    ".MAIN_DB_PREFIX."facture.datef Between Date_Format(Now(), '%Y-%m-01') And CurDate()
GROUP BY
    '.MAIN_DB_PREFIX.'user.rowid
) AS tbl_all
GROUP BY rowid
ORDER BY
    total_sum DESC
```

Comment: had to make minor edits - remove two `,` after `'.MAIN_DB_PREFIX.'user.rowid` and changed GROUP BY to be only per rowid - working perfectly. Thanks for help.